# List all Google Drive (root) Files

Tags: api, google-drive-api

I need to list all Files of Google Drive root Folder/ Directories.

For development I am using Laravel as my Framework.

There are a button at my Application called, "connect with Google Drive" then my developed App ask permission to access google drive of that user.

Then system fetch all the files and do show the all files as list.

However, when using the API to fetch the list of files, I only get a partial list. How do I get the full list of files?

Comment: Can you explain a bit more what "But I won't able to load all files but few." means please?

Comment: Thanks. 
API returns file list but not all files.
I.e : there are 100 files at the drive  but it's returning 60.

Comment: Improved the language to explain what is required, according to the OP's comment.

Answer (score 1):

if you check the [files.list](https://developers.google.com/drive/v3/reference/files/list) method you will notice it has a pagesize parameter.

> pageSize   integer The maximum number of files to return per page. Partial or empty result pages are possible even before the end of the files list has been reached. Acceptable values are 1 to 1000, inclusive. (Default: 100)

By default it is 100 rows you can in cease it to 1000.  After that you will need to paginate over the next rows using pageToken.

if you are not seeing all of your files then you are probably using the Q parameter and limiting it, or there are fewer files on your drive account then you think.